# Cannot make a maven build of spring-cloud-config

Tags: java, spring, ssh, spring-cloud

I'm trying to make a maven build of spring-cloud-config. All the tests in JGitEnvironmentRepositoryTests class are failing with the following exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot clone repository
.
.
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: juancarlos@localhost:/Users/juancarlos/Documents/eclipse/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config-server/target/test-classes/config-repo: Connection refused
```

My SSH keys are properly configured in .ssh folder, as I've tested them with github and worked properly.

Comment: Is your settings.xml for maven is configured to your repository location ?

Comment: @VinayVeluri please, could you explain your question?. Maven is working fine in my machine. The problem is related to the the git repo used for testing under target folder. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After some help from someone with more SSH expertise the problems were the following:

The remote login was not enabled. This was causing a Connection refused exception. I enabled it in System Preferences.

My keys were not authorized. This was causing an Auth cancel exception. I had to run the following command:

```
scp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
```

After this the build only complains because a failing test, but this will be reported to spring-cloud team.